# How do I automate a backup of new MobileMe calendar data

Tags: snow-leopard, automator, ical, mobileme

The new MobileMe iCal data lives in the cloud, and the data on your computer is actually a cache. This support [article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4226) from Apple explains how to backup calendar data by exporting to an .ics file. I would like to automate that process via AppleScript, Automator or any other method (paid software is fine).

The sticking point with AppleScript is selecting the calendar on the left hand column. In Automator I don't think the available actions support this level of automation.

Answer (score 1):

Automator **does** support selecting a Calendar. Using the `Filter` or `Find` actions, you can `Find (Calendar) Where:` and then `(Title) (Contains): ____`

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest using MobileMe's backup but:

> Unlike the previous version of MobileMe Calendar, with the new MobileMe Calendar, the master copy of your calendar data exists in the cloud (on the MobileMe severs). Various calendar clients (such as iCal on Mac OS X and the Calendar app on iOS devices) view a locally-cached copy of the data that is updated whenever a change is made on the server.

So it's a bit tricky! If you comfortable setting AppleScript or Automator to download a file AND you're comfortable making your calendar publicly accessible (assuming someone finds out your public url), you could do this:

> Backing up from me.com/calendar
>
> Go to me.com.
>   Publicly share a calendar.
>   Copy the URL (web address) from that shared calendar and paste it to the address field in you browser. Do not press Enter or Return yet.
>   As shown in the example below, change "webcal" to "http":
>   Example URL from shared calendar: 
>   webcal://www.me.com/ca/sharesubscribe/1.276...
>   Change to:
>   http://www.me.com/ca/sharesubscribe/1.276...  From [MobileMe Help](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4226)

and use that url as your regular download source. I would use Automator and Get Specified URLS and then Download URLS Actions as a starting point.

Comment: This is for a non-shared calendar, so I need to use the export to .ics version.